# How to stop my div from opening and closing right away on body click jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have this simple jQuery snippet to show and hide my div and they work perfectly but I wanted to add so that when someone clicks on the body of the page for the open divs to close and I did it like this:

```
$("body").click(function() {
    if($('#blur-container').is(':visible')) {
        $("#blur-container").animate({width: "0px"})
        $("#mob-menu-wrapper").animate({width: "0px"})
    }
});
```

But now when I click the button that opens the div it immediately closes too. Any help would be much appreciated, and I have searched for other answers but I couldn't get any of them to work for me.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: its so funny how adding just: event.stopPropagation(); fixed everything :) thank you @j08691 thought it would be more complicated then this. :D

Comment: @Blu3 Please accept one of the answers if they have all the information needed for fixing this issue, so that future visitors may easily find the answer.

Comment: @BrantOlsen I added the return false; at the bottom of all my click functions but after that none of the links on my page would open weird?

Comment: The `return false;` would stop the `a` elements from going to their `href` values if your click handlers are on the `a` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you do `event.stopPropagation();` in your click functions to stop the event from bubbling up.

As noted in the comments of the question, see https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ for more information.

I had `return false;` here before, but that will also stop the `a` elements from redirecting or additional events on that element from executing.

Comment: yep thats what I did and it fixed the problem but I put the event.stopPropagation(); right after the start of the function like in the link example and it has been working flawlessly thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your events are being propagated. When you click on the div, first div click event is being invoked and then body click. Do return false in your div click to stop propagation as suggested by @Brant Olsen.